# Memoir: Typeset chapter as section in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

For my Appendix, I'd like to change the look of the ToC such that Appendix-Chapters look like Sections in the main part of the document.

The following code

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*

\chapter{First}
\section{sub}
\chapter{Second}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix 1}
\chapter{Appendix 2}
\end{document}
```

results in the following ToC:

```
1 First
  1.1 sub
2 Second
A Appendix 1
B Appendix 2
```

However, what I would like to have is the following:

```
1 First
  1.1 sub
2 Second
Appendices
  A Appendix 1
  B Appendix 2
```

Comment: BTW: why do you want them to be formatted like this? (just wondering)

Comment: Because my ToC style makes chapters look prominent and because my appendices are not divided into further sections. That's why (i.m.o.) it looks ugly to have multiple such prominent chapter ToC-entries in a sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\cftinsertcode{APP}{
  \setlength\cftchapterindent{\cftsectionindent}
  \setlength\cftbeforechapterskip{0pt}
  \renewcommand\cftchapterfont{\normalfont}
  \renewcommand\cftchapterpagefont{\normalfont}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*

\chapter{First}
\section{sub}
\chapter{Second}
\appendix
\appendixpage
\cftinserthook{toc}{APP}
\chapter{Appendix 1}
\chapter{Appendix 2}
\end{document}
```